# Parsing JSON Data in Swift from Guidebox API

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I'm trying to parse JSON Data using Swift from Guidebox. An example of the data is like this:

```
 {
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 14673,
      "title": "The Golden Girls",
      "alternate_titles": [
        "Golden Palace"
      ],
      "container_show": 0,
      "first_aired": "1985-09-14",
      "imdb_id": "tt0088526",
      "tvdb": 71292,
      "themoviedb": 1678,
      "freebase": "\/m\/01fszq",
      "wikipedia_id": 217200,
      "tvrage": {
        "tvrage_id": 5820,
        "link": "http:\/\/www.tvrage.com\/shows\/id-5820"
      },
      "artwork_208x117": "http:\/\/static-api.guidebox.com\/120214\/thumbnails_small\/14673-9570342022-208x117-show-thumbnail.jpg",
      "artwork_304x171": "http:\/\/static-api.guidebox.com\/120214\/thumbnails_medium\/14673-3759246217-304x171-show-thumbnail.jpg",
      "artwork_448x252": "http:\/\/static-api.guidebox.com\/120214\/thumbnails_large\/14673-2249565586-448x252-show-thumbnail.jpg",
      "artwork_608x342": "http:\/\/static-api.guidebox.com\/120214\/thumbnails_xlarge\/14673-6064109057-608x342-show-thumbnail.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "total_results": 1,
  "development_api_key": "You are currently using a temporary development API key. This API key is for testing only. You have used 57 of 250 available calls. Please see the API docs (http:\/\/api.guidebox.com\/apidocs) for additional information or to generate a production API key."
}
```

It seems that for my case, the simplest way to use the data would be to convert it to [String: Any], as all I really need is "id", "title", and an artwork value. However, all of the (countless) methods I have used are failing because of the fact that "alternate_titles" gets parsed as an NSArray and it makes everything more difficult. 
So far I've tried variations of this method:

```
        do {
        let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
        let datafinal = jsonResult["results"] as! [String: Any]
//Fails around here usually, when the data is converted to [String: Any] or [Any:Any] because of the array.
        let title = datafinal["title"]
        } catch {
            print("JSON Preocessing failed")
        }
```

I've also used the SwiftyJSON library to try to convert the data to more easily readable JSON, but the methods to pull a dictionary from it always fail (I'm guessing due to the structure as well). Anyone have a simple method to get the JSON data from the URL and easily access the values in "results"? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: can you share your efforts ?

Comment: Try this `do {
        let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
        let datafinal = jsonResult["results"] as! NSArary
//Fails around here usually, when the data is converted to [String: Any] or [Any:Any] because of the array.
        let title = datafinal[0].value(forKey: "title")
print("\(title)")
        } catch {
            print("JSON Preocessing failed")
        }`

Comment: create a model class and parse it using object mapper.

Comment: i have create my answer please mind it. if any issue then please let me know , Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
 do {
     let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
     let datafinal = jsonResult["results"] as! NSArary

     let title = datafinal[0].value(forKey: "title")
    print("\(title)")
      } catch {
          print("JSON Preocessing failed")
      }
```

Comment: Could please append description to your solution?

Comment: @dirtydanee my understanding, he just want to get Title from only one index array that is results. next step he has a dictionary inside the array at `index 0` and i am fetching value for key title  `let title = datafinal[0].value(forKey: "title")`. sorry my english is not very good, by d way your answer is also good. :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is access results as an `array`, and take the `first element` of the `array`, what is a `Dictionary`.

In the future, [here](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) is great tool, using what you can check the structure of your data more conveniently, and it might reveals problem like this faster.

```
do {
    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
    guard let results = jsonResult["results"] as? [Any], let resultDictinary = results.first as? [String: Any] else {
        fatalError("Data structure invalid")
    }
    let title = resultDictinary["title"]
} catch {
    print("JSON Preocessing failed")
}
```

Comment: I believe this would work, but there was some confusion in the compiler about the guard statement and how it was set up (I think the two lets were confusing it). Thank you, though! Also, I love that tool, my problem was mainly about how to access it.